# Why didn't Odin regrow Thor's arm?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, odin

In the recent Thor comics, after losing Mjolnir, he also loses his arm to Malekith. 
Odin calls upon a dwarf to forge him a new arm, composed of Uru.
But...why? Odin is a reality warping skyfather who has destroyed galaxies, revived the dead, and created planets from nothing.
Why not simply heal Thor, regrowing his arm. If he wanted Thor to have a magical Uru arm for some reason, he should have been able to create that as well.
So, beyond PIS, is there any reason Odin couldn't simply will Thor to be healed?

Comment: same reason he didn't regrow his own eye?

Comment: While not refering to the Marvel-Comics: Here's another take - why would Odin have Mjolnir made by Sindri and Brokkr in the first place instead of making it by himself (being near-to-almighty and all)?

Comment: Given the personalities of Asgardians in general and Odin in particular, having an awesome wound as a reminder of a well-fought battle is likely not a problem in their minds.  Especially when you have a prosthetic arm, so you don't lose any practical functionality.

Comment: Thor saw [Bucky's](http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Buchanan_Barnes_(Earth-616)) arm and begged his dad to get him one for Christmas/Odinmas?

Comment: @JasonBaker I'm not sure if [Odin's Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesday) is really a special occasion, though.

Comment: Odin is a practitioner of what we parents call "tough love".

Answer (score 10):

#### The answer is: Because he didn't want to. Yes, Odin is completely capable of growing the Odinson a new arm, if he so desired. He didn't. He preferred to let Thor be without one, as with so many things between those two, as a lesson to be learned.

- The relationship between the Odinson and his father has always been a complex one. With Asgard in flux, no longer in its own private dimension, threats to Earth abounding and Asgard not in peak performance, Odin has a lot on his plate. Add to that, a mysterious woman (who granted, to Odin, MAY not be the mystery it is to the rest of us, and woe be unto to anyone if it IS a mystery) suddenly becoming worthy enough to wield one of the mightiest weapons in his kingdom and you have an All-father who is truly peeved.
- Currently The Odinson is not in favor with Odin. He has lost access to Mjolnir. In and of itself a statement so great, there is little left to be said between them. He, however need not be without the resource and since he can have a new arm made for Thor, he does. Keeps his craftsmen happy and resolves the issue of his main enforcer and protector of Asgard, being fully armed...so to speak. He all but says so below:

[image]

[image]

- Eventually, as with all things, Odin will either allow the Odinson to correct his own problem or if he should become worthy enough to wield Mjolnir again, grant him access to either magic or technology which will give him a functioning arm, once again.
- You have to realize, Odin doesn't like correcting the Odinson's mistakes. Remember, when Thor was banned from dying by Hela, and cursed with brittle bones, his body became a mess held together only by armor? (Thor #373) Odin could have fixed this. He did not. It's not his way to fully correct his son's difficulties unless it suits his purpose to do so.

**As a side note:** Odin's eye is lost as a sacrifice to the Well, Mimir in exchange for knowledge of previous Asgards and previous attempts to avoid Ragnarok, the Twilight of the Norse gods. As a sacrifice, the eye can never be regrown. It was the price of knowledge.

**A second side note:** **[Tyr's hand](http://norse-mythology.org/gods-and-creatures/the-aesir-gods-and-goddesses/tyr/)** was also lost as part of a sacrifice to bind the Fenris Wolf. It will also not regrow due to the nature of the sacrifice/betrayal necessary to place an unbreakable chain on the wolf. Odin isn't being cruel to Tyr. It was his destiny to sacrifice his hand for the benefit of Asgard.

Comment: Just one thing: Odin doesn't know who Fem Thor is, and he's reaaaaaaally pissed about it. But the answer makes sense.

Comment: Plus, you know, that makes it a bit less of a jerk move that they haven't regrown Tyr's hand all of this time...

Comment: So, given that a thousand dwarves worked to forge Thor's new arm, how much of a jerk does that make Thor when he decides not to use it?

Comment: It's amusing that it's later revealed even Odin himself couldn't lift Mjölnir anymore. I wouldn't be surprised if he pinned that on Thor, too.